# why can't i change the hovered row backcolor in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid with jquery UI themeroller.  I cannot figure out how to change the backcolor of the row as i am hovering over it.  It shows up with a greyish color (that i assume is coming from somewhere in my jquery UI css theme) when I hover

I have tried to change the

```
.ui-state-highlight
```

css but that doesn't seem to do anything for the actual hover (only affect when you click on a row)

any suggestions for how i can change the backcolor for jqgrid when i highlight over a row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To target the hover state you need to override `.ui-state-hover` class

Try this

```
.ui-state-hover {
   border : 1px solid blue;
   background: green;
}
```

Make sure this is included after the styles for jqGrid are included